# AngularJs Editor which suppports latex markeup

Tags: javascript, angularjs, wysiwyg, angular-ui

I am looking for a WYSIWYG javascript/html editor(similar that to stackoverflow`s editor) which supports

- basic features such as links, bold, italic, image upload etc.
- a special format for code
- latex support for math formulas

For angular I found:

http://textangular.com/

However any other recommendations for an editor which has all these features in one place?

I appreciate your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about StackEdit: https://stackedit.io/ Source: https://github.com/benweet/stackedit/

--Edit--

Looks like StakEdit is an application not an implementation. You could look into PageDown https://code.google.com/p/pagedown/ which StackEdit is built on. Since you are looking for editors specifically for AngularJS (which I missed on the first read through :) ) here are some examples: https://github.com/programmieraffe/angular-editors However it looks like none of them implement the math/latex formulas that is something that StackEdit added for their implementation.

Comment: Thx for your answer! How to use it with angularjs? Any jsfiddle/example?

Comment: I made some edits, but it looks like this might be more complicated than I originally thought :)

Comment: OK. Thx! Is there any tutorial on how to just implement stackedit into a simple ecommerce site ,for example?

Comment: After doing a little more research into StackEdit it looks like it is intended to a standalone application not a component that could be implemented into other applications and therefore doesn't answer your question at all. It could be used as a research point to try and understand how they implemented the features you are looking for but not usable as a component by itself. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You can find ckeditor https://ckeditor.com/ .  I think Complete editor, with Mathjax you can use for Latex